# Mocking a service in Unit Tests in Nestjs

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, nestjs

I'm kinda following this video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_7qA-33Kxg

Where I've 2 services, one of which (service1) depends on service2.

I'm trying to write a unit test for service1 in which I'm trying to mock service2 using custom providers as follows:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        Service1,
        { provide: Service2, useFactory: mockService2 },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service1 = await module.get<Service1>(Service1);
    service2 = await module.get<Service2>(Service2);
  });
```

and mockService2 function is defined as follows:

```
mockService2 = () => ({
  collectionGetQuery: jest.fn(),
  hello: jest.fn(),
});
```

However, when I try to call `mockReturned` on the `collectionGetQuery` (that should be a jest function) I get an undefined function for type (type of original function) error and I don't have access to the hello method meaning that the service is not overridden.

Comment: Your set up looks correct, from what I can tell. Without seeing the error (and possibly the tests) it may be hard to see what's wrong. If you need some examples though [you can find my testing repo here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs) with a bunch of different NestJS sample server tests

Comment: what if you replace `jest.fn()` with `jest.fn().mockReturnValue(...)`?

Comment: It still asks for the arguments that would be sent to the original method.

Comment: So I haven't solved this, but I've made a workaround by not using a Test Module and just create the service class myself and send the mocked dependencies in the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override your provider and use something like this :

```
beforeEach(async () => {
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  providers: [Service2],
}).overrideProvider(Service2).useFactory(mockService2).compile();
  service1 = await module.get<Service1>(Service1);
  service2 = await module.get<Service2>(Service2);
});
```